# How can I hide or modifiy concrete column bases in my finished basement?

Tags: concrete, basement, trim, finishing, column

In my basement are what look like the bases of two support columns poking out at the base of my walls. These walls run in the middle of the basement. The bases are concrete and trapezoidal in shape, wider at the base and more narrow at the top. The problem is they jut out into the room while the column is hidden in the wall. The trim is broken up and it looks awful. Is there a way to hide these that looks nice? Is it possible to modify them? I have thought about grinding down the concrete to keep the columns completely hidden within the wall. I have added a drawing to help describe my problem.

[image]

Comment: Please don't grind your support columns.  They have been designed and speced the way they are.  If you want a square edge, build it up with concrete.  If you don't want to see the junction then pad out your wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use much bigger trim so it won't be "broken up" by being large enough to hide these - of course you'll *lose space everywhere else* in the room as the big trim will be big everywhere.

Grinding down structural supports is *not* a good option.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will try and go with this approach. I will leave the support bases alone ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well:

1. add skirting boards to the walls to match that surface,
2. add 1/2 height walls in wood aka wainscotting to give a decorative finish - could even include heating.